# Prove inequality $x^sy^{1-s} \leq sx + (1-s)y$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given $s \in (0,1)$, prove $$x^sy^{1-s} \leq sx + (1-s)y$$ for $x,y > 0$

Tried some algebraic manipulations but I'm guessing I need to use some trick. 
Any suggestions, hints?

Comment: Apply AM-GM for rational values of $s$, and then argue by continuity.  Or, prove this when $y=1$ first with derivatives.

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/594326/72031

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the natural logarithm is a concave function. That is,
$$\log(sx + (1 - s)y) \ge s\log(x) + (1 - s)\log(y)$$
for all $x, y > 0$ and $s \in [0, 1]$. Using log laws,
$$\log(sx + (1 - s)y) \ge \log(x^s y^{1-s}).$$
Recall that the natural exponential is a monotone increasing function, meaning it respects inequalities. Taking the exponential of both sides yields the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$\ln(x^sy^{1-s})=s\ln(x)+(1-s)\ln(y)\underset{why\ ?}{\leq} \ln(sx+(1-s)y)$$