# Inequality in real analysis $x^a y^{1-a} \le ax+ (1-a)y$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

How to prove that for $a\in (0,1)$ and for all $x,y >0$ we get the inequality 
$$x^a y^{1-a} \le ax+ (1-a)y.$$ It seems not so difficult, yet I'm stuck. I tried to obtain it from Taylor's series
$$x^a y^{1-a} =y\left(1+\frac{x-y}{y}\right)^a \leq y\left(1+ a\cdot \frac {x-y}{y}\right)=ax+ (1-a)y$$
but it only works when $|\frac{x-y}{y}|<1$. 
Should I consider many cases, eg. $x<0$, $y<0 ,\ldots$?

Comment: What you have is the weighted AM-GM inequality. By Bernoulli's inequality, the proof you wrote is true for all positive $x,y$.

Comment: Since both $x$ and $y$ are *positive* and there are certain symmetries at play, I think you can assume without loss of generality that $\lvert x-y\rvert < \lvert y\rvert,$ so your argument works.

Comment: See also: [Prove $a^\alpha b^{1-\alpha} \le \alpha a + (1 - \alpha)b, \; a,b > 0,\; 0 < \alpha < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/594135)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $t\to\ln(t)$ is an increasing and concave function in $(0,+\infty)$. Therefore
$$\ln(x^a y^{1-a})=a\ln(x)+(1-a)\ln(y) \le \ln(ax+ (1-a)y).$$

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use real analysis, you can move all the terms to one side like this:
$$ax + (1-a)y - x^a y^{1-a} \geq 0$$
and look for the extremum of the left-hand side. You'll get $\partial / \partial x = a(1 - x^{a-1})$ and $\partial/\partial y= (1-a)(1 - y^{-a})$. We see that there is an extremum in $x = y = 1$. In this point, the left-hand side is truly equal to 0. So far OK.

The last thing is to compute the Hessian matrix in the point $x = y = 1$ and check that it's positive definite (so the 0 is a minimum). You'll get
$$\begin{pmatrix} a(1-a)x^{a-2} & 0 \\ 0 & a(1-a)y^{-a-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
For $x = y = 1$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a(1-a) & 0 \\ 0 & a(1-a)\end{pmatrix}.$$
That's obviously positive-definite (because $0 <a < 1$).

Of course this is quite a dumb way. The accepted answer is much nicer. This has just an advantage of being quite universal since it doesn't rely on knowledge of other inequalities nor on clever ideas :--).

Answer (score 3):

It's just AM-GM:
$$ax+(1-a)y\geq x^ay^{1-a}$$

AM-GM it's the following thing.

Let $x_i>0$, $\alpha_i>0$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$. Prove that:
$$\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+...+\alpha_nx_n\geq x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}...x_n^{\alpha_n}$$

Comment: Well, AM-GM generalized with weights and restricted to two variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach based on mean value theorem and the credit for this proof goes to G. H. Hardy.

---

Note that there is equality if $x=y$ and we can assume $x<y$ otherwise just put $b=1-a$ and let $b$ play the role of $a$. Let $f(x) = x^{1-a}$ so that $f'(x) =(1-a) x^{-a} $. Now by mean value theorem we have $$f(y) - f(x)=(y-x) f'(c) $$ for some $c$ with $x<c<y$. Therefore $$y^{1-a}-x^{1-a}=(y-x)(1-a)c^{-a}<(y-x) (1-a)x^{-a}$$ Multiplying by $x^{a} $ we get $$x^{a}y^{1-a}-x<(1-a)y-(1-a)x$$ or $$ x^{a}y^{1-a}<ax+(1-a)y$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use the convexity of exponential function, observe that every positive real number has a logarithm, i.e $\exists \ p, q \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x=e^p$ and $y=e^q$.

Therefore we are required to prove $e^{ap + (1-a)q} \le ae^{p}+(1-a)e^q$, which is the definition of convexity. Now the convexity of exponential can be proved by using the fact that second derivative is positive.